# firefox on mac: SAVE AS dialogue. How to make it open file manager so I select where to save the file?

Tags: firefox

I am a mac newbie. I installed firefox on the mac, OS X lion as I am more familiar with firefox from windows.

The problem, which could be a OS X problem, is this:

When I click on a link, say a PDF document, and I tell it to save it instead of opening in the browser, then now I get a new dialog showing where to save to.

But I do not have any way to select something other than what is shown, like on windows.

On windows (and linux) when I do the same thing, and do SAVE, then I am able to navigate to the directory I want to save the file to. On the mac, I can't. I have to select only from the list given. What if I want to save a file somewhere else?

I'd like to be able to navigate using the file manager and select which directory to save to each time.

Is this an OS X restriction? Can one do this using firefox on OS X?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac defaults to a compact save dialog; if you look at it closely, you will notice a button containing a small downward-pointing triangle.  Click that button to get the full file selector dialog.